# Properly display results of mySQL one-to-many query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables:

```
      TRIPS
-----------------
tripID | clientID
```

and

```
              LEGS
--------------------------------
legID | depart | arrive | tripID
```

TRIPS has a one-to-many relationship with LEGS in that there are several `legID`'s per `tripID`. I need to display them in the following format:

```
Trip tripID1:
    Leg legID1: depart1 - arrive1
    Leg legID2: depart2 - arrive2

Trip tripID2:
    Leg legID3: depart3 - arrive3
    Leg legID4: depart4 - arrive4

etc...
```

I've been able to iterate through the legIDs via a `WHILE()` loop, but I'm having trouble embedding a LEGS loop inside the TRIPS loop. My query is:

```
<?php
$legsQuery = "SELECT  trips.tripID, legs.depart, legs.arrive FROM legs, trips WHERE `trips`.tripID = `legs`.tripID";
$legsQueryResult = mysql_query($legsQuery) or die("QUERY LEG ERROR: " . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($legsQueryResult)) {
    print_r($row);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add `order by` clause to sort by trip ID
2. create `$lastTripID` variable to check when you get "legs" from "new trip"
3. [*recommended*] use `join` to select data from multiple tables

Code:

```
<?php
    $legsQuery = "
        select  
            trips.tripID, 
            legs.depart, 
            legs.arrive 
        from 
            legs
            inner join trips on trips.tripID = legs.tripID
        order by
            trips.tripID
    ";
    $legsQueryResult = mysql_query($legsQuery) or die("QUERY LEG ERROR: " . mysql_error());
    $lastTripID = null;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($legsQueryResult)) {
        if ( $row['tripID'] !== $lastTripID ) {
            echo $row['tripID'], "\n";
            $lastTripID = $row['tripID'];
        }
        print_r($row);
    }
```

Comment: +1 I was almost going to submit that same answer. You beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks!! I figured I needed a more complicated query too. This worked great! SO comes through again :)